# Field properties to ensure mean existence

Tags: field-theory

I want to know if there is some properties that when satisfied by a field, we guarantee the existence of a "mean" of two scalars in that field.
I can formulate my question as: is there any properties (or a kind) of a field, that guarantees that: 
$$
\forall (x,y) \in F, \exists z \in F \text{ such as } x + y = z + z
$$
(+ denoting the addition over the field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field has caracteristic different from 2, your property is satisfied

As it is a field, you have a unit u for multiplication. If the characteristic is different from 2, $(u+u)^{-1}$ exists.

$(u+u)^{-1}$ verify $(u+u)^{-1}+(u+u)^{-1} = u$.

Indeed, 
$$u+u = u+u $$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow (u+u)(u+u)^{-1}+(u+u)(u+u)^{-1} = u(u+u)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (u+u)^{-1}(u+u)(u+u)^{-1}+(u+u)^{-1}(u+u)(u+u)^{-1} = u(u+u)(u+u)^{-1}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (u+u)^{-1}+(u+u)^{-1} = u $$

then if you take $z = (u+u)^{-1}(x+y)$, it follow that $z+z = x+y$

Comment: I have another question in mind but that seems really trivial to post as a new question: Could we conclude that every ordered field (so with characteristic 0) is always dense in itself. I know it is a topology concept, but given the field is ordered, defining dense will be: $\forall (x,y) \in F \exists z \in F \text{ such as } x<z<y$

Answer (score 1):

Since $F$ is a field, it is equivalently to the claim that for every $x\in F$ there exists a $y\in F$ with $x = y+y$. That is true, if the characteristic of $F$ is not $2$.

As $k=1+1\ne 0$ is invertible, we have
$$ x = k \cdot k^{-1} x = (k^{-1} x) + (k^{-1} x). $$

Comment: There exists fields different from $\Bbb F_2$ wiith characteristic 2.

Comment: @Tryss aren't they isomorphic? I will edit.

Comment: No, you have infinite fields with characteristic 2 ;)

Comment: @Tryss okay. thx

Comment: Just to add exemples of infinite fields with characteristic 2 : the algebraic fractions of $\Bbb F_2$ and the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_2$